# Web Essentials não exibe opções

Tags: visual-studio-2015, minificação

Instalei o [Web Essentials 2015](http://vswebessentials.com/) no [Visual Studio Community 2015](https://www.visualstudio.com/vs/community/), mas ao tentar fazer a minificação de alguns arquivos css, as únicas opções exibidas foram as que estão na imagem abaixo.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Já removi e instalei novamente o Web Essentials, mas nada mudou. Também desistalei o Visual Studio e instalei novamente (o que me custou muito tempo), mas mais uma vez tive o mesmo resultado.

As seguinte opções eram para aparecer:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como posso resolver isso?

Comment: Quais as opções que deveriam aparecer ali?

Comment: Todas essas: http://i.imgur.com/hes9ueL.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Segundo o [site](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MadsKristensen.WebEssentials20153) da extensão Web Essentials 2015 no *marketplace* a minificação e *bundling* de JS/CSS, bem como algumas outras funcionalidades, foram movidas para plugins específicos.

Por favor baixe o plugin relevante e verifique se o item de menu necessário aparece.